# How can I define variables that follow a naming pattern?

Tags: list-manipulation, variable-definitions

Let's say I have this enormous list of a million elements, and I want to access this list piecemeal in non-intersecting sublists of length ten. If

```
t = { (* long list*) }
```

I would like each sublist to be named

```
t1to10 = Partition[t, 10][[1]]
t11to20 = Partition[t, 10][[2]]
```

and so on, or equivalently,

```
t1to10 = t[[1;;10]]
t11to20 = t[[11;;20]]
```

etc. However, I don't have the luxury of being able to define $10^5$ different variables. Is there a convenient way of defining all my variables in the exact pattern I want, e.g.

```
tXXtoYY = Partition[t, 10][[YY/10]]
(* where XX = YY/10 - 9 *)
```

or

```
tXXtoYY = t[XX;;YY]
```

Comment: Why not use `Span[]` then?

Comment: @J.M. I was on the fence about using `Partition` over `Span` when I was first writing the question, but I settled on one and figured someone would point out a better/easier option. I've edited my question to include the latter.

Comment: `l = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10^6];
myP[n_Integer] := l[[10 (n - 1) + 1 ;; 10 n]];
Print[myP[1], myP[10^5]]`

Comment: So you're essentially copying the entire huge list piecemeal to smaller lists? That seems like it wastes a lot of memory. What is the intended purpose? Instead, what I would do is define a **function** that extracts the desired parts from the big list when needed.

Comment: @Jens In reality, the huge list has length `12 326`, and the lists are composed of text strings - some lengthier than others - that I'm supposed to test in a search engine. The segmentation of the megalist was intended to make it easier for me to keep track of which inputs have been tested.

Comment: @J.M. I realize now what you meant by your suggestion after seeing march's answer. Sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: That's okay. I hope you picked something up from march's nice answer. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a pretty natural way, I think, that almost matches your variable names.

```
list = Range[51];  (* for testing *)
t[x_Integer, y_Integer] /; y == 9 + x := t[x, y] = list[[x ;; y]]
t[11, 20]
(* {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20} *)
```

Using `t[11, 20]` rather than `t11to20` serves the purposes of being easily functionalized, is just as readable, allows you to directly index the variable names, and allows memoization (i.e. once `t[11, 20]` has been evaluated once, it's stored in memory from there on out).

---

I recommend *against* doing `tXXtoYY`, because the programmatic construction of such a variable name is ugly and unnatural, and it doesn't allow you to manipulate the different lists programmatically (and functionally).

Comment: This works for me! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's worth putting up an answer that addresses the "naming pattern" part mentioned in the question. As I mentioned in my comment, I don't see why you'd want to store the parts individually in separate variables, so I will focus only on a function that allows you to use exactly the **variable names** that you want, but without assigning any values to them. That potentially saves a lot of memory.

Then the question reduces to extracting the correct parts of a big list, given a symbol with the naming convention you required. Here is the answer to that question:

```
t = RandomWord["CommonWords", 100];

u = RomanNumeral[Range[100]];

getNamed[s_Symbol] := Module[{name = SymbolName[s]},
  Part[Symbol @@ StringCases[name, LetterCharacter .., 1], 
   Apply[Span, ToExpression@StringCases[name, NumberString]]]]

getNamed[t1To10]

(*
==> {"holler", "perturbation", "inform", "grind", "unstudied", \
"knucklehead", "trefoil", "uracil", "carhop", "deceptively"}
*)

getNamed[t11To20]

(*
==> {"labeled", "forswearing", "laurels", "welt", "foundling", \
"reservation", "popularize", "foolishly", "dinette", "warble"}
*)

getNamed[u31To40]

(*
==> {"XXXI", "XXXII", "XXXIII", "XXXIV", "XXXV", "XXXVI", \
"XXXVII", "XXXVIII", "XXXIX", "XL"}
*)
```

The main ingredient in the function `getName` is [`SymbolName`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SymbolName.html), which converts the input to a string on which I then do pattern matching to extract the name of the large list and the parts.

Comment: What is the benefit of using `SymbolName` versus `ToString` here?

Comment: @march With the specific naming convention of the OP, there's no difference to `ToString`, I'd say. The difference is their handling of `Context`s, which isn't an issue here.

Comment: I see (sort of: not really versed in dealing with `Context`s). Anyway, this is definitely a clever way of actually answering the OP's request that avoids the unnaturalness of programmatically creating variable names. +1